# vaadin 10 - Push - Label won't update

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10

MainView include InformationCOmponent:

```
@Push
@Route
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {       
    InformationComponent infoComponent;

    public MainView(@Autowired StudentRepository studentRepo, @Autowired Job jobImportCsv, @Autowired JobLauncher jobLauncher, @Value("${file.local-tmp-file}") String inputFile) {     
    [...] // some stuffs

    infoComponent = new InformationComponent(studentRepo);
    add(infoComponent);
    }

    //update when job process is over
    private void uploadFileSuccceed() {
       infoComponent.update(myUploadComponent.getFile());
    }
```

InformationComponent:

```
public class InformationComponent extends HorizontalLayout {

    StudentRepository studentRepo;

    Label nbLineInFile = new Label();

    VerticalLayout componentLeft = new VerticalLayout();;
    VerticalLayout componentRight = new VerticalLayout();;

    public InformationComponent(StudentRepository studentRepo) {
    [...] // some init and style stuff

    addLine("Nombre de lignes dans le fichier", nbLineInFile);
    }

    private void addLine(String label, Label value) {
    componentLeft.add(new Label(label));
    componentRight.add(value);
    }

    public void update(File file) {
    try {


        long nbLines = Files.lines(file.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset()).count();

        System.out.println("UPDATED! " +nbLines); // value is display in console ok!
        UI.getCurrent().access(() -> nbLineInFile.setText(nbLines)); // UI is not updated!!
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

When I call InformationComponent from MainView **the Label is not update in the browser**.

```
UI.getCurrent().access(() -> nbLineInFile.setText(nbLines))
```

also try wwith @Push(PushMode.MANUAL) and ui.push(); but doesn't work either...

Complete source code is here: https://github.com/Tyvain/ProcessUploadedFile-Vaadin_SpringBatch/tree/push-not-working

Comment: It's working now. I actually did a big mistake in my InformationComponent, not adding properly the Label. The complete working version can be found here: https://github.com/Tyvain/ProcessUploadedFile-Vaadin_SpringBatch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem here is that `uploadFileSuccceed()` is run from a background thread, in which case `UI.getCurrent()` will return `null`. This would cause a `NullPointerException` that either kills the background thread or alternatively the exception is caught and silently ignored by the caller. Another alternative is that `uploadFileSuccceed()` happens through a different browser window and thus also a different `UI` instance, which means that the changes would be pushed in the context of the wrong `UI`.

For exactly these reasons, `UI.getCurrent().access(...)` is generally an anti pattern, even though it's unfortunately quite widely used in old examples.

You can check whether this is the cause of your problem by logging the value of `UI.getCurrent()` in the beginning of the `update` method, and comparing that to the value of `UI.getCurrent()` e.g. in the constructor of `InformationComponent`.

To properly fix the problem, you should pass the correct `UI` instance through the entire chain of events originating from whatever triggers the background processing to start. You should also note that it might be tempting to use the `getUI()` method that is available in any `Component` subclass, but that method is not thread safe and should thus be avoided in background threads.

As a final notice, I would recommend using the `Span` or `Text` component instead of `Label` in cases like this. In Vaadin 10, the `Label` component has been changed to use the `<label>` HTML element, which means that it's mainly intended to be used as the label of an input component.

Comment: all UI are the same at all steps: constructor MainView ui: com.vaadin.flow.component.UI@4a5d32df
constructor InformationComponent ui: com.vaadin.flow.component.UI@4a5d32df
update InformationComponent ui: com.vaadin.flow.component.UI@4a5d32df

Comment: "Label component has been changed to use the <label> HTML element" Do you mean I should link my java to an actual html file? because the goal was to build an app with no html.

Comment: If `UI.getCurrent()` gives the right value, then it seems like `update` is run during regular request handling which in turn means that push is irrelevant. I would instead look at really basic things, e.g. whether `nbLineInFile` is actually added to to some layout that is part of the application.

Comment: Regarding `Label`, the thing is that everything eventually ends up as HTML (or actually DOM elements) in the browser because that's what the user will see. Vaadin Flow manages what happens in the browser so that you don't have to do any HTML files or such, but you still sometimes need to be aware that different component classes have different semantical meaning from the browser's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information provided by Leif you should do something like the following example.

At runtime, when this [`HorizontalLayout`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/10.0.4/com/vaadin/flow/component/orderedlayout/HorizontalLayout.html) subclass object is attached to a parent `UI` object, its [`onAttach`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/10.0.4/com/vaadin/flow/component/Component.html#onAttach-com.vaadin.flow.component.AttachEvent-) method is called. At that point we can remember the UI by storing its reference is a member variable named `ui`. Actually, an [`Optional<UI>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html?is-external=true) is returned rather than a [`UI`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/10.0.4/com/vaadin/flow/component/UI.html) object, so we need to test for null, though it should never be null at point of `onAttach`.

```
public class InformationComponent extends HorizontalLayout {

    UI ui;

    StudentRepository studentRepo;

    Label nbLineInFile = new Label();

    VerticalLayout componentLeft = new VerticalLayout();;
    VerticalLayout componentRight = new VerticalLayout();;

    public InformationComponent(StudentRepository studentRepo) {
        [...] // some init and style stuff

        addLine("Nombre de lignes dans le fichier", nbLineInFile);
    }

    private void addLine(String label, Label value) {
        componentLeft.add(new Label(label));
        componentRight.add(value);
    }

    public void update(File file) {
    try {
        long nbLines = Files.lines(file.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset()).count();

        System.out.println("UPDATED! " +nbLines); // value is display in console ok!
        this.ui.access(() -> nbLineInFile.setText(nbLines)); // UI is not updated!!
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (UIDetachedException e) {
        // Do here what is needed to do if UI is no longer attached, user has closed the browser
    }

    @Override  // Called when this component (this `HorizontalLayout`) is attached to a `UI` object.
    public void onAttach() {
        ui = this.getUI().orElseThrow( () -> new IllegalStateException("No UI found, which should be impossible at point of `onAttach` being called.") );

}
```

Comment: onAttach() is supposed to be Override ? because there is only onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent). Or should I pass UI from my mainView (in the constructor for example)?

Comment: @Tyvain Yes, the `onAttach` method here is an override of the [`Component::onAttach`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/10.0.4/com/vaadin/flow/component/Component.html#onAttach-com.vaadin.flow.component.AttachEvent-) method (`Component` being an interface implemented by `HorizontalLayout`). That method is called when this `HorizontalLayout` object is eventually attached to a `UI` for presentation to the user. I added the `@Override` annotation to make this more clear.

Comment: I changed this code a bit to account for [`getUI`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/10.0.4/com/vaadin/flow/component/Component.html#getUI--) returning an `Optional<UI>` rather than a `UI` object.

Comment: In this particular code example, what is the benefit of remembering the `UI` reference in a `ui` member variable? Why not use `this.getUI().orElseThrow(…).access(…)` rather than `this.ui.access(…)`? I am not seeing how this relates to [Answer by Leif Åstrand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51978235/642706).

Comment: Thanks @Basil gor the corrections. You could use getUI() instead of stored ui reference, however getUI() is not 100% threadsafe either. Its much better than UI.getCurrent() approach, but there were are corner cases.